# CalendarExtender wrongly positioned after scrolling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, calendarextender

I am adding a CalendarExtender to a page, using the default styles.  When I click the calendar button to trigger the calendar popup, the calendar displays normally.  However, when I scroll down and click the button again, the calendar's position is not where it should be, as seen below.

[image]

Why is this occuring and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:** A bit about the implementation of this page.

The CalendarExtender and TextBox are part of a WebPart added to a SharePoint 2007 Page.  I am creating the extender like so:

```
textBox = new TextBox() { ID = "textBox" };
Controls.Add(textBox);

calendar = new CalendarExtender()
    {
        ID = "ceStartDate",
        TargetControlID = textBox.ID,
        PopupPosition = CalendarPosition.Right,
        PopupButtonID = image.ID
    };
Controls.Add(calendar);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp) of the page?  Also, what browser is it? I have seen this issue on pages with invalid/old DOCTYPEs with IE6-7 in Quirks mode.

In quirks mode, javascript values(like scroll position), can be off, resulting in a bad render.  You should ensure you have a valid DOCTYPE that forces IE into standards mode like..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: The page did not have a DOCTYPE.  I added the DOCTYPE from above and this fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I came across the same problem today.

Wrap your textbox and calendarExtender in a div with `position:relative;`

That fixed the problem i was facing, i hope it does the trick for you too

Comment: +1: This worked for me. I was having the correct DOCTYPE and I still wondered what could be the problem. Hope that others will explore your answer is the one accepted won't work for them. For me this solution worked on multiple browsers: Chrome, Mozilla, Opera, IE (both 8 and 9).

Comment: I already had a doctype. And similar styling worked for me. Here is the reference :
http://languagelassi.blogspot.in/2012/08/blog-post.html

Comment: @Dogoku Fine... In our project, we are using JavaScript calender, it's still showing in the bottom position. Please mention if there is any workaround to fix it.

Comment: @techdo what do you mean? can you make a new question or give me an example, link, something?

Comment: Perhaps this is only happening to me, but when I wrap it in a relative div as you say, the calendar positioning is correct but the bottom half of the calendar is cut off. I have my textbox and extender wrapped inside the div which is inside a <td>. Does this have something to do with it?

Comment: Depends on your css. from the sound of it, either that div or a parent of it has `overflow:hidden;` which will cut off any content bigger than itself. Create a question and link it here. Either me or someone else will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an old post I found trying to solve this situation for myself (unsuccessful following previous answers), I thought my solution to the same issue might be relevant to others.

- We where using an **outdated version**: 3.0.xxx
- We had to **upgrade to latest version**: 4.1.xxx

Above versions is the AjaxControlToolkit dll version - not the version you see on NuGet, today the NuGet package ("Ajax Control Toolkit") will be something like 7.xxx.

**FYI - My research:** I've been using the samples of latest AjaxControlToolkit version to verify if my bug was solved if I upgraded (since I knew exactly how to reproduce my position-issue). At least one of the two sites below should work:

- http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ (official - slower)
- http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ (independent - faster)