# AjaxControlToolKit Calendar doesn't appear

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to get the AjaxControlToolkit Calendar object to populate on an aspx page within firefox (latest build) .  My environment consists of .net 3.5, vs 2010, and vista latest sp.

Here is the code I am executing:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                                </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolKit:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </ajaxToolKit:CalendarExtender>
```

EDIT

By populate I mean display with data.  At the moment it doesn't even show up, I am exploring other packages to use at the moment because I am on a schedule.  I will look into posting more code up.

Additional code:
http://pastebin.com/m59d8392e

Comment: Can you post some more code and clarify your issue a little bit more?  What do you mean by populate? Does the calendar just not show? Are you expecting a calendar image button to show on the page next to the text box?

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue somewhat similar to this a while back and asked the below question.  The answer was to ensure that a doctype definition existed at the top of the document.  Try it out and see if it fixes your issue.

[CalendarExtender Positioning Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958555/calendarextender-positioning-problem)

Comment: I appreciate the link however it did not rectify the issue